# Xcode 4 NSURL Error

Tags: swift, xcode4, nsurl

I get this error then doing this? My goal its to fetch an image from the firebase and view it in my tableview.

[image]

Comment: Are you *pretty sure* about "Xcode *4*"?! Did you mean "Xcode *9*" or Swift 4?

Comment: Never include code as a picture in your question. Include it as text and use code formatting.

Comment: OK so format a text URL to image ?

Answer (score -1):

You should use `URL(string: profileImageUrl)` instead of `NSURL(string: profileImageUrl)` because URLSession expecting URL not NSURL.

Comment: Thanks it Worked :) so now i can fetch image from firebase right ?

Comment: Actually you presented a snippet of code, I can't say with that. Keeping URL instead of NSURL can get rid of ambiguous error, that's I can say :)